# Asynchronous transaction handling in mutiny/jooq

Tags: java, jooq, mutiny

I am trying to save two objects in a single transaction. On error, I would like my transaction to roll back.

Here is the current attempt:

```
public Uni<Response> save(...) {
return Uni
    .createFrom()
    .completionStage(dslContext.transactionResultAsync(configuration -> repo
        .insert(... , configuration.dsl())
        .flatMap(dataRecord -> Uni
            .createFrom()
            .publisher(configuration
                .dsl()
                .insertInto()
                .set()
                .returning())
            .map(ignore -> Response
                .builder()
                .build()))))
    .flatMap(i -> i);
```

with `repo.insert` looking like:

```
Uni<DataRecord> insert(..., DSLContext dslContext) {
return Uni
    .createFrom()
    .publisher(dslContext
        .insertInto()
        .set()
        .returning())
    .map(dataRecord -> new DataRecord()
        .set(...))));
```

The configuration is based on [quarkus-jooq custom context version 2.0](https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-jooq/blob/main/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/jooq/runtime/JooqCustomContext.java), with two additions:

```
settings.setBindOffsetDateTimeType(true);
settings.setRenderSchema(true);
```

However. there is no rollback happening in case the second insert fails (I forced it by violating a `not null` constraint). I see the exception in my test. I also see the first object. So what would do the trick?

Comment: How do you configure your `configuration`?

Comment: updated the question w/ configuration